# Fetching and parsing data from wikipedia

Tags: python, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup, fetch

I'm trying to fetch and parse some data from wikipedia, for analysis. I'm trying to extract the data to analyse the correlation among the factors in columns and the happiness score itself.

But the file is not working as expected.
In fact, the final file is empty. I tried debugging, but it didn't work:

```html
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from csv import DictWriter

def get_page(url):
    html_file = requests.get(url)
    return html_file

def parse_html(html_file):
    parsed_html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_file.text, 'html.parser')
    
    t = parsed_html.find_all('table')[1]
    
    tr = t.find_all('tr')[0]
    headers = []
    for header in tr:
        for z in header:
            if isinstance(z, bs4.element.NavigableString):
                header_name = z.strip()
                headers.append(header_name)
    
    headers_original = headers
    countries = []
    prev_rank = ""
    for ln, row in enumerate(t.find_all('tr')[2:]):
        country = {}
        i = 0
        col_values = row.find_all('td')
        
        while i < len(headers):
            col = col_values[i]
            value = col.text.strip()
                
            if headers[i] in ('Country or region',):
                value = str(value)
            else:
                value = float(value)
            country[headers[i]] = value
            i += 1

        countries.append(country)

    return headers, countries

def write_csv(filename, data, fieldnames):
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

def main():
    source = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report"
    print(f'Fetching URL {source}...')
    page = get_page(source)

    print(f'Parsing {source}...')
    headers, countries = parse_html(page)

    print(f'Writing to a CSV file 1...')
    write_csv('worldhappiness.csv', countries, headers)

    print(f'Parsing table 3 (simpler table) {source} ...')
    headers, countries = parse_html(page)

    print(f'Writing to a CSV file 2...')
    write_csv('worldhappiness2.csv', countries, headers)
    
    print(f'Writing to a CSV file 3...')
    write_csv('worldhappiness3.csv', countries, headers)
    
    print(len(countries))
    print(len(headers))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler to use pandas for this purpose:

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report')
tables[4]
```

The output is your target table.